# How to install user defined instances from AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

How can I make user defined instances from AWS CloudFormation?

Example:

Question: How many instances do you want?
Answer: 4

AWS CloudFormation should install 4 same instances.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear how you can create 4 instances with ASG?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need custom-resource for that. You can just create your instances as part of [AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html). ASG will create required number of instances once you set `DesiredCapacity` and `MaxSize`. So if you want 4 instances, you set these values to 4.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Autoscaling Group - `DesiredCapacity` and `MaxSize` - [AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html)
2. Spot fleet ( cost savings by 90%) - `TargetCapacity` - [AWS::EC2::SpotFleet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-spotfleet.html)